# Is there an ESLint rule to find files with a `.jsx` file extension which don't contain actual JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I've found several files in my project which used to contain JSX in them, but don't anymore, i.e. they could be renamed to `.js`/`.ts`. I would like to find such files automatically and would have thought that ESLint (specifically `eslint-react`) already contained such a rule. However, I couldn't find one.

Do you know of such a rule or should I be preparing a patch for `eslint-react`?

Comment: A little while ago, I was also looking for something like this. I'm pretty sure this does not yet exist.